# a lot of LNK2019 errors trying to follow vulkan tutorial

Tags: visual-studio, glfw

I was following [this](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment) tutorial on vulkan but I'm having trouble setting up the environment. My code looks exactly the same. I don't know what else to send here other than the logs since I have no clue what I could've done wrong. There were a lot more errors but stackoverflow didn't let me post, they were all pretty much the same tho. Here's the error log:

```
1>main.cpp
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage referenced in function createHelperWindow
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageW referenced in function createHelperWindow
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageW
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PeekMessageW referenced in function createHelperWindow
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PeekMessageW
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterDeviceNotificationW referenced in function createHelperWindow
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_UnregisterDeviceNotification referenced in function _glfwPlatformTerminate
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExW referenced in function createHelperWindow
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExW
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformTerminate
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyWindow
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow referenced in function createHelperWindow
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ToUnicode referenced in function _glfwUpdateKeyNamesWin32
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MapVirtualKeyW referenced in function _glfwUpdateKeyNamesWin32
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_MapVirtualKeyW
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SystemParametersInfoW referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SystemParametersInfoW
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateDCW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteDC referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDeviceCaps referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetGammaRamp
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @user7860670 I couldn't find anything there that helped me unfortunately

Comment: Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies setting.  The standard values there got wiped out somehow.  Add back kernel32.lib, user32.lib, gdi32.lib.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks so much! that removed a lot of the errors but there are still 5 left, are there any other standards i could add?

Comment: Nvm I fixed it and answered

Comment: In Qt creator you need to add `LIBS *= -luser32` to your .pro file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue I went into my Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies and checked the box that says "Inherent from parents or project defaults" and it now compiles without any errors.